# Python 3 text file with space-separation to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

With Python 3, I want to make lists from a text file (`hoge.txt`) which is like:

```
a1 b1 c1 d1
a2 b2 c2 d2
a3 b3 c3 d3
....
an bn cn dn
```

The lists are supposed to be like:

```
a = [a1, a2, ...., an]
b = [b1, b2, ...., bn]
c = [c1, c2, ...., cn]
d = [d1, d2, ...., dn]
```

Here is a python code that I could make, but are there any ways to make it simpler and better?? I would like to use list comprehension if possible, which may be more efficient in memory use?.....

```
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
d=[]
for line in open('hoge.txt'):
    parts=line.split()
    a.append(parts[0])
    b.append(parts[1])
    c.append(parts[2])
    d.append(parts[3])
```

Comment: is the number of lines in your text file fixed?

Comment: PS. for file interaction, it is better to work with the `with` statement

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes it is.

Comment: @MaartenFabré I am ashamed,,, I dont know about 'with'. I will see thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use a csv reader (with delimiter `' '`) to read the file and then transpose the data with `zip(*data)`

```
from csv import reader

with open('hoge.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = reader(file, delimiter=' ')
    transposed = (list(item) for item in zip(*data))
    # transposed = zip(*data)  # produces tuples: ('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'an')
                               # instead of lists. depends on your needs.

a, b, c, d = transposed
print(a)  # ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'an']
```

the last assignment works for 4 lines in the file only. but you should be able to tweak that to your needs. this is a variant:

```
a = next(transposed)  # ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'an']
b = next(transposed)  # ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'bn']
....
```

if you want to get the transposed directly with a list comprehension you could to this (thanks to [Maarten Fabré](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1562285/maarten-fabr%c3%a9)'s comment):

```
with open('hoge.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = reader(file, delimiter=' ')
    transposed = [list(item) for item in zip(*data)]
# [['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'an'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'bn'], 
#  ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'cn'], ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'dn']]
```

your need to transpose the data does not make it easy to find a memory-efficient version. you would have to iterate over the file multiple times if you want to save memory.

Comment: if you do `transposed = [list(item) for item in zip(*data)]` you get a nested list, which seems to me what the OP asks

Comment: sure, that way you get the transposed 'matrix'. but it seemed to me the OP wanted to assign the first column to a variable called `a`, etc.

Comment: ` I would like to use list comprehension if possible, which may be more efficient in memory use?.....` that's why I said 'seems'. That way it is also more robust if there are not exactly 4 columns (as long as the number of columns remain the same in the whole file)`

Comment: ooops. right! has that always been in the question? will update my answer. thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, hiro and Maarten!
I am not familiar with python standard such as csv and zip...
I will see them. 

Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy.loadtxt for the task.

```
import numpy as np
file_data = np.loadtxt('hoge.txt', usecols=(0,1,2,3))
a = file_data[:,0]
b = file_data[:,1]
c = file_data[:,2]
d = file_data[:,3]
```

Comment: This will *definitely not be more memory efficient*, and anyways, `numpy` is rather overkill if you simply want to read a space-delimited text file...